# Split word by capital letter

Tags: php

I want to split a word by capital letter in PHP

For example:

```
$string = "facebookPageUrl";
```

I want it like this:

```
$array = array("facebook", "Page", "Url");
```

How should I do it? I want the shortest and most efficient way.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) with the a [look-ahead assertion](http://php.net/regexp.reference.assertions):

```
preg_split('/(?=\p{Lu})/u', $str)
```

Here `\p{Lu}` is a [character class of all Unicode uppercase letters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.unicode). If you just work with `US-ASCII` characters, you could also use `[A-Z]` instead.

Comment: @JohnSmith You’ve found it where? Another SO question?

Comment: in php.net i found something like this

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = "facebookPageUrl";

preg_match_all('((?:^|[A-Z])[^A-Z]*)', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

http://ideone.com/wL9jM