# Divide string in array

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split word by capital letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645445/split-word-by-capital-letter)

how i can transform one string in one array with the rule for capitalize letters? 
Ex:

$string = "TimBurton";

$array[0] = "Tim";

$array[1] = "Burton";

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $string);
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/0E2DqO