# Split at capital letters in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-split

I found this similar question, but it doesn't answer my question, [Split word by capital letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645445/split-word-by-capital-letter).

I have a string which is [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). I want to break up that string at each capital letter like below.

```
$str = 'CamelCase'; // array('Camel', 'Case');
```

I have got this far:

```
$parts = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', 'CamelCase');
```

But the resulting array always ends up with an empty value at the beginning! `$parts` looks like this

```
$parts = array('', 'Camel', 'Case');
```

How can I get rid of the empty value at the beginning of the array?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY flag like this:

```
$parts = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', 'CamelCase', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

See the [documentation for *preg_split*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

Answer (score 3):

You need a positive-lookbehind. Try this:

```
$parts = preg_split('/(?<=\\w)(?=[A-Z])/', 'CamelCase')

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Camel"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Case"
}
```

Comment: Seems to not work with `C CamelCase`, might need adjustment if there may be spaces.

Comment: @Wesley, spaces weren't in the original requirement, but this would work: preg_split('/(?:(?<=\\w)(?=[A-Z])| )/', 'C CamelCase')

Answer (score 2):

Array filter can be used to remove all empty values:

```
$parts = array_filter( $parts, 'strlen' );
```

Comment: He wants to generate the correct array, not fix the broken one.

Comment: Given Kara's answer this isn't the best answer but, in my defence, the asker specifically asked "How can I get rid of the empty value at the beggining of the array?"